# Unexpected Output using char array in TicTacToe Class

Tags: c++, arrays, eclipse

It was pointed out to me [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132534/tictactoe-implementation-with-classes/132557#132557) that passing an board array into member functions of a tictactoe class was a bit of bad practice.  It makes more sense to make it a private member variable and manipulate it internally without main ever having knowledge of it.

I attempted to implement this change in my code and now i'm receiving very strange character outputs when attempting to print the board to the console:

**Image of Output**

[image: Strange Character Output]

I have just begun using classes so I imagine that I have made an elementary mistake and it's showing through in this way.  Any thoughts?

**Main**

```
    //implementation of TicTacToe
//Using classes this time

#include <iostream>
#include "TicTacToeClass.h"


int main()
{

    //Assumes no play unless user decides they want to play and initializes game variable to TicTacToe class
    bool play = false;
    TicTacToe game;

    play = game.getUserWantToPlay();

    //allows for multiple games to be played
    while(play == true)
    {

        char playerWinner = 'n';
        char player = 'X';

        //single game iteration
        while(playerWinner == 'n')
        {

            game.drawBoard();
            game.getPlayerMove(player);
            playerWinner = game.checkForWin(player);

            if(playerWinner == 'n')
            {
                player = game.togglePlayer(player);
            }
        }

        game.drawBoard();

        play = game.getUserWantToPlay();

    }

    return(0);
}
```

**Class Header**

```
* TicTacToeClass.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 15, 2016
 *      
 */

#ifndef TICTACTOECLASS_H_
#define TICTACTOECLASS_H_


class TicTacToe
{

    public:
        bool getUserWantToPlay();
        void drawBoard();
        void getPlayerMove(char player);
        char togglePlayer(char player);
        char checkForWin(char player);

    private:
        char squareArray[9];

};

#endif /* TICTACTOECLASS_H_ */
```

**Class Implementation**

```
//TicTacToe class implementation
//Leeroy Jenkins

#include "TicTacToeClass.h"
#include <iostream>

char squareArray[9] = {'1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

bool TicTacToe::getUserWantToPlay()
{

    char response;
    bool invalidResponse = true;
    bool play = false;

    while(invalidResponse == true)
    {

        std::cout << "Would you like to play a new game of TicTacToe? (y/n) " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> response;

        if(response == 'y')
        {
            invalidResponse = false;

            play = true;
        }
        else if(response == 'n')
        {
            std::cout << "No Problem!";
            invalidResponse = false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please input a proper response (y/n)" << std::endl;
        }

    }

    return play;
}
void TicTacToe::drawBoard()
{

    //draws the game board with updated characters for each player

        std::cout << "Player 1 (X) - Player 2 (O)" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;

        std::cout << "    |     |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " " << squareArray[0] << "  |  " << squareArray[1] << "  |  " << squareArray[2] << std::endl;

        std::cout << "____|_____|____" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;

        std::cout << " " << squareArray[3] << "  |  " << squareArray[4] << "  |  " << squareArray[5] << std::endl;

        std::cout << "____|_____|____" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;

        std::cout << " " << squareArray[6] << "  |  " << squareArray[7] << "  |  " << squareArray[8] << std::endl;

}

void TicTacToe::getPlayerMove(char player)
{
    //Gets player move and stores in board array for display through next iteration

    bool playerMoveFound = false;
    char playerTurn = '0';
    char playerMove = '0';

    if(player == 'X')
    {
        playerTurn = '1';
    }
    else
    {
        playerTurn = '2';
    }


    while(playerMoveFound == false)
    {
        std::cout << "Player " << playerTurn << " please make a move" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> playerMove;

        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            //If finds the array number makes the change to the iteration...prevents x or o movement
            if(playerMove == squareArray[x] && playerMove != 'X' && playerMove != 'O' && playerMove != 'x' && playerMove != 'o')
            {
                squareArray[x] = player;

                playerMoveFound = true;
            }

        }
        if(playerMoveFound == false)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid player move..." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

char TicTacToe::checkForWin(char player)
{
    char playerWin = 'n';
    int testForTie = 0;

    //Tests winning combinations
    if(squareArray[0] == squareArray[1] && squareArray[1] == squareArray[2])
        {
            playerWin = player;
        }
        else if(squareArray[0] == squareArray[3] && squareArray[3] == squareArray[6])
        {
            playerWin = player;
        }
        else if(squareArray[0] == squareArray[4] && squareArray[4] == squareArray[8])
        {
            playerWin = player;
        }
        else if(squareArray[1] == squareArray[4] && squareArray[4] == squareArray[7])
        {
            playerWin = player;
        }
        else if(squareArray[2] == squareArray[4] && squareArray[4] == squareArray[6])
        {
            playerWin = player;
        }
        else if(squareArray[2] == squareArray[5] && squareArray[5] == squareArray[8])
        {
            playerWin = player;
        }
        else if(squareArray[3] == squareArray[4] && squareArray[4] == squareArray[5])
        {
            playerWin = player;
        }
        else if(squareArray[6] == squareArray[7] && squareArray[7] == squareArray[8])
        {
            playerWin = player;
        }
        else
        {
            //Tests for a tie game
            for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                if(squareArray[x] == 'x' || squareArray[x] == 'o' || squareArray[x] == 'X' || squareArray[x] == 'O')
                {
                    testForTie++;
                }
            }

            if(testForTie == 9)
            {

                playerWin = 't';
            }
        }

    if(playerWin == player)
    {
        if(player == 'X')
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "Congratulations player 1!  You Win!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "Congratulations player 2!  You Win!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if(playerWin == 't')
    {
        std::cout << "Tie!  You should play again to settle the duel!" << std::endl;
    }

    return(playerWin);

}

char TicTacToe::togglePlayer(char player)
{

    player = player == 'X' ? 'O':'X';

    return(player);

}
```

Comment: Answers below are correct - you didn't initialize charArray[] of your class. What you have at top of .cpp file is global variable. It has the same name as a variable from your class, but it's different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear that your `TicTacToe` class has a constructor that initializes its `squareArray` class member, your game's board.

```
char squareArray[9] = {'1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
```

This declares some variable called `squareArray`, in the global scope. It does not initialize your class member of the same name, and this doesn't have anything to do with the class's member.

As such, the class member's initial contents consist of uninitialized memory, with random garbage. You're seeing the results of the undefined behavior, displaying the contents of an uninitialized array to `std::cout`.

You need to have a class constructor that initializes the class member, accordingly.

Comment: Hi Sam.  I am attempting to add this and am struggling.  Could you help?  I tried doing char TicTacToe() : squareArray {'1','2','3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
{} and i'm receiving an error that says symbol squar array could not be resolved.

Comment: You have to declare a default constructor "`TicTacToe();`" inside the class definition in the header file, then define it in the translation unit: "`TicTacToe::TicTacToe() : squareArray{'1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'} {}`". For additional examples of class constructors, go read your favorite C++ book on this topic.

Comment: Yep I actually did just that and found the proper syntax.  Had it wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You never initialized `squareArray` in `TicTacToe` which is what

```
std::cout << " " << squareArray[0] << "  |  " << squareArray[1] << "  |  " << squareArray[2] << std::endl;
```

uses.  When you did

```
char squareArray[9] = {'1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
```

in the implementation file you make a global char array named `squareArray`.  You do not initialize the class member variable `squareArray`.  You need to write a default constructor that initializes the member variable.  You could use

```
TicTacToe() : squareArray{'1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'} {}
```